# Is it possible to scan matter on an atomic level?

Tags: atomic-physics, particle-detectors, microscopy

is it possible to develop a model of a piece of ordinary matter and scan it to develop a model of what kind of elements are in the matter? Similar to an MRI scan?

If it's not possible, why? What challenges would need to be overcome?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean like this: https://www.nanoscience.com/techniques/scanning-tunneling-microscopy/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have microscopes that can see and manipulate samples on an atom-by-atom level (electron microscopes). You can also use spectroscopy to tell what types of atoms are present or xray diffraction to tell how they are arranged.

We cannot, however, develop a complete map of where **all** the atoms are at a moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few techniques for seeing at the atomic or near-atomic level: tunneling electron microscopy (TEM), scanning tunneling microscopy (STM), and atomic force microscopy (AFM). TEM can resolve atoms and comes with a sensor called EDS that uses X-rays to determine elemental composition at a pretty small scale. STM images individual atoms, but can't really determine elemental composition without already having a guess as to what the sample is made of (building a model, as you put it). AFM can be fitted with different kinds of probes to determine, for example, the magnetic properties of a sample at the near-atomic level.

The one problem with these techniques is that you can't image "ordinary matter" with them. Samples imaged have to be extremely flat and prepared specially. In the case of STM it also has to be at least semiconducting.